# Get user email, from user table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, methods

In my ASP.MVC site user have additional field email, so now i want to reset password by sending token to email address like this:

```
var token = WebSecurity.GeneratePasswordResetToken(model.Pesel);
var userID = WebSecurity.GetUserIdFromPasswordResetToken(token); 
var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account", new { UserId = userID, code = token }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
```

But the problem is how can I get email address that I have added to User table?

It will be nice to create method like:

```
WebSecurity.GetUserIdFromEmailResetToken
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you? Such as

```
    public UserEmailTable GetUserIdFromEmailResetToken(int userEmailId)
    {
          return  _db.UserEmail.Where(s => s.UserEmailId == userEmailId)
    }
```

this allows you to get the user email by Id.